# How to access WildFly from another computer on same local network?

Tags: jakarta-ee, networking, wildfly

I'm working on a Java EE app using WildFly server. I would like to access it from another computer on the same local network. I have changed the `standlone.xml` as below:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.173.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.173.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:192.168.173.1"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

I have disabled my firewall, but I still can't access it.

Comment: Can you share a "netstat -na | grep LISTEN" (assuming a Unix-like environment) on the machine running WildFly?  Or do you mind running with "-b 0.0.0.0"?  That makes WildFly listen on any address.

Comment: when i try running with  -b 0.0.0.0  i get some errors

Comment: What errors are you getting with the "-b"?

Comment: You should post your startup command line of Wildfly.... possible problems: not using the standalone.xml, overwriting parameters (like "jboss.bind.address") with other values, ...